# Why does this code lead to deadlock?

Tags: c++, pthreads, deadlock, cilk, cilk-plus

I am surprised to see from `pstack` that this code leads to deadlock! I don't see a reason for the same.

```
pthread_mutex_t lock;

_Cilk_for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  int ai = A[i];
  if (ai < pivot) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    A[ia++] = ai;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }
  else if (ai > pivot) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    A[ib++] = ai;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }
  else {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    A[ic++] = ai;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }
}
```

I am just using mutexes to make sure that access to A is atomic and serialized.

- **What is wrong with this code to lead to deadlock?**
- Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: Side note: This looks like a horrible way to implement a parallel quick sort?

Comment: Are you calling `pthread_mutex_init` on `lock`?

Comment: This code will not deadlock.  A deadlock requires, at least, holding a lock while trying to acquire another lock.  You are never doing that.

Comment: But, yet, it is deadlocking right in front of me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's code inside a function, then you're not initialising the mutex correctly. You need to set it to `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` (for a simple, default mutex) or do a `pthread_mutex_init()` on it (for more complex requirements). Without proper initialisation, you don't know what state the mutex starts in - it may well be in a locked state simply because whatever happened to be on the stack at that position looked like a locked mutex.

That's why it always needs to be initialised somehow, so that there is no doubt of the initial state.

Another potential problem you may have is this:

```
int ai = A[i];
```

You *probably* should protect that access with the same mutex since otherwise you may read it in a "half-state" (when another thread is only part way through updating the variable).

---

And, I have to say, I'm not sure that threads are being used wisely here. The use of mutexes is likely to swamp a statement like `A[ia++] = ai` to the point where the vast majority of time will be spent locking and unlocking the mutex. They're generally more useful where the code being processed during the lock is a little more substantial.

You may find a non-threaded variant will blow this one out of the water (but, of course, don't take my word for it - my primary optimisation mantra is *"measure, don't guess"*).

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I don't understand, how does the value of lock matter?

Comment: @paxdiablo: Any idea why a missing init() might lead to a deadlock? I am pretty sure it is a deadlock.

Comment: @Lazer: yes, without proper initialisation as per the pthreads doco, you don't know the initial state. It may _start_ in a locked state for all we know, just because that was what was on the stack when you allocated it. See the update.

Answer (score 3):

Your `pthread_mutex_t lock` is not properly initialized, so, since it is a local variable, it may contain garbage, and might be in a strangely locked state. You should call [pthread_mutex_init](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_init.html) or initialize your `lock` with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`

As others complained, you are not wisely using mutexes. The critical sections of your code are much too small.

Answer (score 1):

AFTER you fix or otherwise verify that you are in fact initializing your `lock`:

`pstack` may be privy to control mechanisms introduced by `_Cilk_for` that are interfering with what would otherwise be reasonable `pthread` code.

A quick search shows there are [mutex solutions for use with Cilk](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/cpp/lin/index.htm#cref_cls/common/cilk_resolve_data_races.htm) - intermixing Cilk and pthreads isn't mentioned.  It does look like Cilk is a layer on top of pthreads - so if Cilk chose to put a wrapper around `mutex,` they likely did so for a good reason.   I'd suggest staying with the Cilk API.

That aside, there's a more fundamental issue with your algorithm.  *In your case,* the overhead for creating parallel threads and synchronizing them likely dwarfs the cost of executing the code in the body of the for-loop.  It's very possible this will run faster without parallelizing it.

Comment: Yes, in-fact this is 10 times slower than serial version for some workloads.